# Setting A Paper on Mathematical Puzzles

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, puzzle

I need to set a paper for High School Students on Mathematical Puzzles which make the use of logic, simple combinatorics and algebra. Can people provide new and innovative questions.

The questions should be preferably easy on calculations and more leaned on puzzles.The level of question can vary from Medium to Advanced, but preferably within Mathematical scope of a Senior Year High School Student (12th Grade).

Comment: It would help if you could provide a bit more in the way of criteria. E.g., level of difficulty (puzzles for high school students in general, or for accelerated students, or for competition, and target grade level etc.), and/or if you could provide examples of acceptable problems...

Comment: What do you mean, "Set a paper?" Do you mean "write a paper?"

Comment: I meant to set a question paper.

Comment: If you care to look, there are hundreds of puzzles on this site. Maybe thousands! Many of them are suitable for your purpose.

Comment: I know, I am scanning thorugh. I asked for help if you could suggest some good ones out of them.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "set a question paper." Do you mean "assign" it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews He means he is going to write an exam for a class. "Set" is another word for this used by English speakers from India. There was a similar question on this site about the word "doubt" being used for "question."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to visit the *Art of Problem Solving's* website (AOPS.org) for some great potential problems. For example, see [AOPS: Resources for mathematics competitions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Resources_for_mathematics_competitions), which you can explore further for potential problems of interest.

You also might want to check out MathForum.org's [Math-problems+puzzles](https://web.archive.org/web/20171117011946/http://mathforum.org/students/high/probs.html) link; there, you'll find both problems and links to other sites with problems (including those related logic, algebra, geometry, and elementary combinatorics) of varying level of difficulty, geared for high school students.